# How to move the page up when keyboard shows on iOS in safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

How can I move the page up when the keyboard shows on safari on the iPhone? Right now when someone focuses on an input box, the keyboard overlaps the input. I want the keyboard to be below the input. Can someone please help? How do we reverse the effect when the input no longer is focused on?

Answer (score 0):

Add this tag to the `<head>` of the HTML:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Edit:
Another possible cause of the problem is that the inner height of the window is no longer the full view height of the window when the keyboard is presented. Where you would normally size the page to fit within the window using css height `100vh`, you now need to size the page to fit within the window's inner height.
One way to do this is by setting the page's height to the window's inner height when a page resize happens. Heres's an example using jquery:

```js
$(window).resize(() => {
    $('#myPage').height(window.innerHeight)
})
```

Comment: Right now I have "content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1". Are you saying I need maximum scale too?

Comment: Yes, that should cause the page to slide up above the keyboard.

Comment: I tried that and it still doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: @RueVitale see latest edit